# TypeError: DriverAction() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nargs'

Tags: python, click, command-line-interface, argparse

I am currently working on a CLI tool using python's **argparse** module. It continuously throws this error anytime I run the program. I tried removing both the **help** and **nargs** supported arguments and still, nothing seems to work.

**Full Error traceback**

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sharhan/.local/share/virtualenvs/backupdb-CXGj3PlQ/bin/backupdb", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('backupdb', 'console_scripts', 'backupdb')()
  File "/home/sharhan/DEV/PYTHON/CLI-TOOLS/backupdb/src/backupdb/cli.py", line 42, in main
    args = create_parser().parse_args()
  File "/home/sharhan/DEV/PYTHON/CLI-TOOLS/backupdb/src/backupdb/cli.py", line 27, in create_parser
    parser.add_argument(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/argparse.py", line 1428, in add_argument
    action = action_class(**kwargs)
TypeError: DriverAction() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nargs'
```

**This is the code:**

```py
from argparse import Action, ArgumentParser
from os import pardir


def DriverAction(Action):
    """
    Namespace is a class that stores the arguments passed in the CLI.
    collect driver & destination from values and store them in the namespace
    using the dot notation appropriately
    """
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        driver, destination = values
        namespace.driver = driver.lower()
        namespace.destination = destination


def create_parser():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description="""
    Back up PostgreSQl databases Locally or to AWS S3
    """
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "url", 
        help="URL of the database to backup"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--driver",
        nargs=2,
        action=DriverAction,
        required=True,
        help="How and where to store the backup",

    )
    return parser  


def main():
    import boto3
    from backupdb import pgdump, storage

    args = create_parser().parse_args()
    dump = pgdump.dump(args.url)
    if args.driver == 's3':
        client = boto3.client('s3')
        storage.s3(client, dump.stdout, args.destination, 'mybackupdb.sql')
    else:
        with open(args.destination, 'wb') as outfile:
            storage.local(dump.stdout, outfile)
```

Comment: To define a subclass use `class DriverAction(Action):`.  You are using the function syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking too much I couldn't even figure minute things